# TypeScript Array<T> inheritance

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, typescript, prototype

I have some experimental code that inherits from `Array<T>`...

```
class SuperArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    constructor(...items) {
        super(...items);
    }

    public clear(): void {
        while (this.length > 0) {
            this.pop();
        }
    }
}

var array = new SuperArray("Matt", "Mark", "Luke", "John");

array.clear();
```

**[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20SuperArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(...items)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(...items)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20clear()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20(this.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.pop()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20array%20%3D%20new%20SuperArray(%22Matt%22%2C%20%22Mark%22%2C%20%22Luke%22%2C%20%22John%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aarray.clear()%3B)**

I've added the `clear` method just to illustrate the problem. When this is compiled and run in the browser, I get...

> TypeError: array.clear is not a function

How is this completely valid code in TypeScript, but not valid in JavaScript, and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BTW this is a breaking change in TS2.1

This [TS documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work) has a recommendation for a changing the prototype in your constructor

```
constructor(...items) {
    super(...items);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, SuperArray.prototype);
}
```

Comment: Strange...that makes my code "seem" like it's all working...what's actually going on here?

Comment: Also, is that why https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12488 is coming in the 2.2 release?

Comment: You can read something here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11919 It kind of worked in older TS versions but this caused other issues. #12488 is unrelated

Comment: Oh, this is nice, wasn't aware of that. Though it's kind of a hustle to do that for every subclass.

Comment: @NitzanTomer My guess is that __extends using Object.setPrototypeOf(...) will fix this in the 2.2 release.

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles into this when targeting `es5`:

```
var SuperArray = (function (_super) {
    __extends(SuperArray, _super);
    function SuperArray() {
        var items = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            items[_i] = arguments[_i];
        }
        return _super.apply(this, items) || this;
    }
    SuperArray.prototype.clear = function () {
        while (this.length > 0) {
            this.pop();
        }
    };
    return SuperArray;
}(Array));
var array = new SuperArray("Matt", "Mark", "Luke", "John");
array.clear();
```

It's not possible to extend native objects like that, which is why you're getting this error.
If you'll target `es6` then the compiled js will look like this:

```
class SuperArray extends Array {
    constructor(...items) {
        super(...items);
    }
    clear() {
        while (this.length > 0) {
            this.pop();
        }
    }
}
var array = new SuperArray("Matt", "Mark", "Luke", "John");
array.clear();
```

And that will work just fine (if you run it in a browser that supports es6 classes).

---

#### Edit

I'll just paste parts of the article [Subclassing builtins in ECMAScript 6](http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/subclassing-builtins-es6.html) which explains why it can't be done with `es5`:

> **Allocation obstacle: MyArray allocates the wrong kind of object**
>   Array instances are special – the ECMAScript 6 specification calls
>   them exotic. Their handling of the property length can’t be replicated
>   via normal JavaScript. If you invoke the constructor MyArray then an
>   instance of MyArray is created, not an exotic object.
>
> **Initialization obstacle: MyArray can’t use Array for initialization**
>   It is impossible to hand an existing object to Array via this – it
>   completely ignores its this and always creates a new instance.

Comment: What does ES6 do to allow  this that ES5 cannot do (please feel free to be technical)

Comment: There's a good article about it: [Subclassing builtins in ECMAScript 6](http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/subclassing-builtins-es6.html)

Comment: Revised my answer with quotes out of this article which explain why it can't be done with `es5`

Answer (score 0):

Since Typescript 2.2 you can access `new.target` from the constructor.

Thus you can make the following call after having called `super()`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
```

It should solve the propotype chain issue